Oracle SQL define a variable
I'm using Oracle SQL, and the column tradedate in this table is of type DATE. I want to define a current_date where I will manually input a specific date each time. Then, I need to calculate some metrics within a certain time range(30 days in this case), such as average, std, etc. Where did I go wrong?
I tried a few verison but got error message like 'invalid SQL statement', 'error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound', 'Oracle Database Error：ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected'.
Any guidance would be great!
DEFINE current_date = TO_DATE('08-Mar-2024', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')

SELECT
r.DVPCustodianID,
COUNT(r.TYPE) AS count_of_eventType,
sub.avg_30_count_of_eventType,
sub.stddev_30_count_of_eventType,
sub.max_30_count_of_eventType,
sub.min_30_count_of_eventType
FROM
DNA_CAT_GWIM.REPORTABLEORDEREVENTS r
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
r1.DVPCustodianID,
AVG(CASE WHEN r1.tradedate BETWEEN &current_date - 30 AND &current_date THEN r1.cnt END) AS    avg_30_count_of_eventType,
STDDEV(CASE WHEN r1.tradedate BETWEEN &current_date - 30 AND &current_date THEN r1.cnt END) AS stddev_30_count_of_eventType,
MIN(CASE WHEN r1.tradedate BETWEEN &current_date - 30 AND &current_date THEN r1.cnt END) AS min_30_count_of_eventType,
MAX(CASE WHEN r1.tradedate BETWEEN &current_date - 30 AND &current_date THEN r1.cnt END) AS max_30_count_of_eventType
FROM
(
SELECT
DVPCustodianID,
tradedate,
COUNT(TYPE) AS cnt
FROM
DNA_CAT_GWIM.REPORTABLEORDEREVENTS
GROUP BY
DVPCustodianID, tradedate
) r1
GROUP BY
r1.DVPCustodianID
) sub ON r.DVPCustodianID = sub.DVPCustodianID
WHERE
r.tradedate = TO_DATE('&current_date', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')
GROUP BY
r.DVPCustodianID,
sub.avg_30_count_of_eventType,
sub.stddev_30_count_of_eventType,
sub.max_30_count_of_eventType,
sub.min_30_count_of_eventType;

I tried a few verison but got error message like 'invalid SQL statement', 'error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound', 'Oracle Database Error：ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected'. Any guidance would be great

You are declaring the current_date as data and then you are trying to convert into a date, can you try comment this line ad see if it works , TO_DATE('&current_date', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')

DEFINE is a sql*plus command that remembers a string that you can then include in your SQL. So, it is not the result of TO_DATE('08-Mar-2024', 'DD-Mon-YYYY') that you are storing in your variable, but the text itself. You can prove this for instance with DEFINE current_date = sysdate AS current_dt FROM dual and then SELECT &current_date; which works, because &current_date is replaced by the whole string after DEFINE current_date =.

This gets a little bit simpler if you get in the habit of writing dates like date '2024-03-08'. Then define current_date = 2024-03-08 and change your query to use date '&current_date'.

You need to either define the variable as just a string value and then apply the to_date() function to that consistently, or define it as an expression and then use that consistently. At the moment you're mixing them. You have
DEFINE current_date = TO_DATE('08-Mar-2024', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')

and a mix of usage like
BETWEEN &current_date - 30 AND &current_date

which is fine, and
r.tradedate = TO_DATE('&current_date', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')

which is not. With set verify on you would see that is substituted as
r.tradedate = TO_DATE('TO_DATE('08-Mar-2024', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')

and in this version of the code that gets ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. If you remove the to_date() from that line to match the other references:
r.tradedate = &current_date

then that would substitute as
r.tradedate = TO_DATE('08-Mar-2024', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')

which is now valid.

You could also use a date literal, which is slightly shorter and also avoids the possibility of this breaking if it's run in a session with different NLS language settings (which might not recognise 'Mar' as a valid month abbreviation):
DEFINE current_date = DATE '2024-03-08'

Your code also assumes that tradedate always has its time components set to midnight, which may be true for your data. If it isn't then you will need to change that filter condition to use a date/time range too, and maybe replace the between conditions with >= and < conditions.

Define variable just as a string; omit function call there - use it in query, when transforming string to a valid date value.
For example:
SQL> select min(hiredate) from emp;

MIN(HIREDA
----------
17.12.1980

SQL> define my_date = '17.12.1980'                 --> no TO_DATE function here
SQL> select empno, ename, job, sal
  2  from emp
  3  where hiredate = to_date('&my_date', 'dd.mm.yyyy');    --> TO_DATE is here
old   3: where hiredate = to_date('&my_date', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
new   3: where hiredate = to_date('17.12.1980', 'dd.mm.yyyy')

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            800

SQL>


If you look at DEFINE documentation, it says

Specifies a user or predefined variable and assigns a CHAR value to it (...)

so - yes - define it as a string and then apply to_date function to it.
